# First N sec not played from pulseaudio over HDMI on Android TV

Tags: troubleshooting, android-tv

I start tv, select input source, set default sink for pulse audio(`pacmd set-default-sink 0`) and start some playback in mplayer. For some reason, there is like 3-5s delay between command being executed and sound actually coming out from tv(sony). After that, I can immediately turn off mplayer, and if I rerun, there won't be any delay/audio missing. However if I wait for like 30s, it will start over again.

I really don't know what is causing this issue. Is it pulseaudio, android tv, gpu, or it's a some feature of sound over hdmi?  Is it somehow fixable? I mean for initial first connection — not ideal, but OK, but then I'd like to 'hear' all executions of all potentialy launched apps start playing immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause:

check this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/218444/sound-output-starts-delayed

so I commented out this line:

```
 load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

in file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, and issued `pulseaudio -k` waited for restart and now it works without any delay. Hurray!